# Node.js Zsync ( or other Network Folder Replication ) library

Tags: node.js, zsync

**The problem:**

Binary data exists on a server, and is regularly updated. It should be replicated to clients in a bandwidth efficient way and should operate over HTTP(S). An ideal solution would use delta patching and also delete files that were no longer present on the server, that were on the client.

**Possible Solutions:**

- ZSync ( What I was previously using in Java )
- Any other library that you guys might know of.

To be clear this is a Node.JS problem. I am really hoping that I do not need to write a ZSync library, but my initial searches turned up nothing.

Thanks for any help!